# How to add ternary operator to an on press event

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following code in a react native component:

```
            renderItem={({item, index, section})=> {
               return (
                 <View style={{ backgroundColor: index % 2 == 1 ? "#F0FBFC" : "white" }}>
                   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableRow} onPress={ () => navigateMember(absentData[item].uid, section.title) }>
                     <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.first}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.last}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.phone}</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
                 </View>
               )
             }}
```

If section.title == "Absent" I need to onPress to be as is:

```
onPress={ () => navigateMember(absentData[item].uid, section.title) } but if it's not I need it to be 
onPress={ () => navigateMember(visitData[item].uid, section.title) } can this be done in a ternary operator?  Currently it's not working for me.  I can do a method but I'm wondering if there is away to do it as a ternary.  I tried:

{sectionList.title == "Absent" ? (
onPress={ () => navigateMember(absentData[item].uid, section.title) }
) : (
onPress={ () => navigateMember(visit[item].uid, section.title) }
)}
```

The above errored.  I feel like I'm just making up syntax there.  Any idea if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that changes is the first argument, so the conditional operator only needs to replace the first argument.

```
onPress={ () => navigateMember((sectionList.title === "Absent" ? absentData : visitData)[item].uid, section.title) }
```

But it'd be more readable to create a block for the function so you can extract the uid in the first line.

```
onPress={ () => {
  const { uid } = (sectionList.title === "Absent" ? absentData : visitData)[item];
  return navigateMember(uid, section.title);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this

1. Condition for specific parameter

```js
onPress={() => navigateMember(sectionList.title == "Absent" ? absentData[item].uid : visit[item].uid, section.title)}
```

2. if else

```js
onPress={ () => {
  if(sectionList.title == "Absent"){
    navigateMember(absentData[item].uid , section.title)}
  } else {
    navigateMember( visit[item].uid, section.title)}
  }
}
```